# Banach space and eventually constant sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the space of the eventually constant sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $$E=\{(a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n; \exists \ N \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{such that} \  \ \forall  \ n\geq N, a_n=0 \}.$$

I must prove that there is no norm that makes this space be a banach space.  I think that i should use baire's theorem, but i'm having some hard time on finding a basis for this.

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, not the finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Show that $F_N = \{x \in E\mid x_m =0 \text{ for } m > N\}$ is closed and nowhere dense in $E$, for all integers $N$. Their union is $E$...

Comment: @DavidMitra no, the sequences must be eventually $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question (phone hid some of it).